# Working with hotkeys in emacs

Tags: emacs, locale, key-bindings, emacs24

I'm using `en` and `ru` locales. When I use `ru` locale - hotkeys does not work.

How I can make hotkeys work in all locales?

Comment: Try to use `(setq default-input-method "russian-computer")` and change layout by emacs's internal `toggle-input-method` (C-\ hotkey) instead of systemwide layout switching.